# Multi Value Arrays

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to cure a multi line problem in my sql exports to a table from `DataSet1`.

Basically one field (`SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC`) can contain many values.  My unique identifier value is the `UCN`. `FULL_NAME` is also unique per UCN.  I am trying to combine all possible answers in the same field in a table seperated by commas, so am typing this in as an expression in a blank column in a table.

```
=join(LookupSet(Fields!FULL_NAME.Value, Fields!UCN.Value, 
      Fields!SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC.Value, "DataSet1"),",")
```

My expressions just returns blank.

```
UCN:FULL_NAME:SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC  

1.....:ABC.............:Help  
1.....:ABC.............:Me  
1.....:ABC.............:Please
```

I would like one field that contains        "Help,Me,Please" in my table

Becomes

```
UCN:FULL_NAME:New_Field  

1.....:ABC.............:Help,Me,Please
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9deb9/9)**

```
SELECT t1.UCN, t1.FULL_NAME,
       newCol =REPLACE( (SELECT SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC AS [data()]
                  FROM mytable t2
                  WHERE t2.UCN = t1.UCN
                  ORDER BY t2.SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC 
                  FOR XML PATH('')
            ), ' ', ' : ')
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY t1.UCN, t1.FULL_NAME ;
```

Comment: HI  My dataset contains many more fields and foreign keys, so was hoping to do it as an expression in the table rather than write the SQL statement.  Is there a way of amending my lookupset function?

Comment: Hmm, I thought you were after `TSql`, since you have tagged the question as `sql`, `sql-server-2008`.

Comment: HI Sorry, I am new to this forum, so didn't really know which tag to use.  Sql and sql2008 seemed reasonable as that is the report builder I am using?  I should have mentioned which tools I am using.

Answer (score 1):

You were so close with your expression; the issue is you're comparing `FULL_NAME` to `UCN` in the `LookupSet` comparison, which is getting no matches and hence your empty `Join` result.

Use something like:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!UCN.Value
    , Fields!UCN.Value
    , Fields!SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC.Value
    , "DataSet1"), ",")
```

or:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!FULL_NAME.Value
    , Fields!FULL_NAME.Value
    , Fields!SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC.Value
    , "DataSet1"), " ")
```

I did a simple test with the first expression based on your Dataset, works for me:

[image]

**Edit after comment:**

You can reference individual elements in the Join array and use this to display these elements in separate columns, using an expression like:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!UCN.Value
    , Fields!UCN.Value
    , Fields!SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC.Value
    , "DataSet1")(0)
```

Change the element number at the end of the expression to `(1)` or `(2)` to get the required element. End result:

[image]

Couple of things I can think of:

1. Order is important - if you're not ordering your Dataset, you might get inconsistent results with `Join` and `LookupSet`. Order at the database or Tablix level.
2. Not sure how this will work if you're going to need dynamic numbers of columns, but if it's always going to be three (or any fixed number) you'll be OK.

Or alternatively you can think about performing a `pivot` query at the database level to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Needed the first two arguments to be the same.

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer solves your issue, please consider upvoting and/or setting it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Hi  Will do.  One other thing on this topic.  The idea here is to get all of my data onto one line in a table, I'm not sure my idea above is the optimal solution.  Ideally I would like this data set to have one column for each piece of data.  You would have three columns of data for SUB_ATTRIBUTE_DESC, instead of comma separating it.   Is this possible?

Comment: Updated with a few suggestions on changing this into separate columns, with a few caveats.